Issue with User Required to Enter Username and Password on Logon in Windows 7
I am encountering an issue with a Windows 7 machine that is part of a domain. When a user attempts to log on, they are prompted to enter their username and password. Ideally, I would like the logon screen to display all the user accounts that are present in the PC, so that I just have to enter the password for login and not require manual input of the username on logon, even after pc reboot/restart.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any solutions to prevent the username prompt on logon for domain users?
Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
Edit: The accounts are domain accounts that require to be displayed permanently on lock screen after logging in once

All local, not domain accounts ? Or what you mean under "accounts that are present in the PC"

All domain accounts that have been previously logged in, at least once

built in providers save only last logged user. if you want more wide list you need custom cred provider
